# When to use `std::cmp::ordering` instead of an `if` statement in Rust

Tags: if-statement, rust, comparison

When should I use `std::cmp::ordering` in a `match` block instead of using an `if`/`else if` statement? Is readability the only difference?

For example:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() {
    match 2.cmp(&2) {
        Ordering::Less => println!("Less than 2."),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("Greater than 2."),
        Ordering::Equal => println!("Equal to 2."),
    }
}
```

vs.

```
fn main() {
    if 1 < 2 {
        println!("less than 2.");
    } else if 1 > 2 {
        println!("Greater than 2.");
    } else if 1 == 2 {
        println!("Equal to 2.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is readability the only difference?

I would say it's more of a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) thing.

If you look at the second sample, it's messy:

> ```
> fn main() {
>     if 1 < 2 {
>         println!("less than 2.");
>     } else if 1 > 2 {
>         println!("Greater than 2.");
>     } else if 1 == 2 {
>         println!("Equal to 2.");
>     }
> }
> ```

1. There is no `else` clause. If you mess up the conditions it'll just do nothing.
2. If the last one was an `else` clause, you'd still better put an `assert!(1 == 2)` inside to make sure that it's only taken when the two are equal (and not because you made a mistake in the previous conditions).
3. And even then you would still have a repetition between `1 < 2` and `1 > 2`.

Compare that to the `match`:

> ```
> fn main() {
>     match 2.cmp(&2) {
>         Ordering::Less => println!("Less than 2."),
>         Ordering::Greater => println!("Greater than 2."),
>         Ordering::Equal => println!("Equal to 2."),
>     }
> }
> ```

1. You cannot accidentally forget a case, it's guaranteed to be exhaustive.
2. The condition is only written once, no need to "reverse" it or anything.

Therefore, `if` vs `match` is a matter of number of different outputs really:

- use `if` if there is one or two branches,
- use `match` if there are three branches or more.

A `match` is just more maintainable than an `if`/`else` chain.

---

*Note: I personally think that `cmp` is rarely used directly. It is more meant as an implementation device, allowing you to implement a single function to get all 4 inequality operators. Coming from C++, it's a relief...*

Comment: "Coming from C++, it's a relief...", well, they are trying: [spaceship operator in C++20](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison)

Comment: @mcarton It takes decades to add small things in C++ while a beautiful language has been done in few years with Rust. That's why I am done with C++. They can add whatever they want in 10 years, that's too late.

Comment: personally I find this harder to read, have to actually think about it

Comment: @mcarton: Yes. Now, we just need the meta-class proposal to be able to automatically implement it as well...

Comment: @Keatinge: I find easier/harder to read subjective, I prefer to focus on objective measurements. A single condition is less likely to be out of sync with itself.

Comment: I'd say there's the *potential* for more efficient code with the `cmp` version, as you "know" that that comparison is only going to happen once. It's possible (but totally incorrect) for `lt` and `gt` to have side effects.

Comment: @Shepmaster: It depends. Rust `sort` originally used `cmp`, and now uses `<` because it leads to better code generation/execution.

Comment: @MatthieuM. but in that case it *only* uses `lt`, not *both* `lt` and `gt`. I'm saying that (1 `cmp`) may be better than (1 `lt` + 1 `gt`).

Comment: @Shepmaster: Well, yes, now. It probably used a slightly different algorithm before. One issue with `cmp` is branch-prediction, AFAIK binary branch prediction is much easier than multi-target branch prediction. Thus, I would not trust any guess on the performance of either 1 `cmp` or 1 `lt` + 1 `gt`; especially when the execution of said `gt` only occurs when `lt` returned false ;)